# THTTPRIO, SOAP and error 503 when doing too frequent requests

Tags: delphi, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to access a web service that has a quirk. It appears that if you do too many requests (I'm guessing more than one or two per second) you end up with an error 503. If you retry after a few seconds, then everything is fine.

Now, my problem is that I'm using Delphi to consume this service. The generated files have the communication part abstracted away - so I'm trying to come up with a neat solution for this throttle problem. Right now I'm resorting to `sleep()` between calls...

Has anybody had a similar problem before? Is there a global hook or setting to add some cool down period after a successful request?

Comment: Could it possibly be a WinInet problem?  I have noticed that there are strange problems with WinInet.  What version of Internet Explorer do you have installed, and what OS?  Do you have any proxy configured in the Internet Explorer options pages? What authentication are you doing (Http/https/basic/digest/etc)

Comment: it might be that the server has some internal issues? are you running multiple requests from different threads? the 503 may be due to too much traffic or who knows what happens on the server side... more info would be helpful.

Comment: The service is out my control (this is for electronic invoicing, the server is from the taxes office.) I'm guessing sure it is some form of throttling on their side to avoid too many requests. I have reproduce the problem using SoapUI so I don't think is a WinInet problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle a temorary error like 503, the message processing queue could use an incrementing delay time, a failed request will increase the waiting time (up to a defined maximum). If a request was successful, the delay is reset.

So I would for example start with a 500 msec interval. Every time the request fails, the interval will be multiplied by two up to a maximum delay of 16 seconds. If a request returns without error, the interval is reset to its initial value of 500 msec.

Comment: Funnily enough, this is what I have (I wait `NumTries * WaitInterval`)

Answer (score 2):

By definition: http status code 503: Service Unavailable. The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state.

As 500-599 present a server side error, happening all the time, on Web service or Web site. For 503, slowing down the frequency of the requests from your client program is a good way to go, and you might need to consider UI design as well if your client program has GUI>

Comment: Yup, this is what I'm trying to do. I have to consume several web services and I cannot anticipate the workload, so I would like to have a nice centralized way to throttle my output. I'm even thinking of an event queue...

Answer (score 1):

How about a TTimer? That way your app isn't locked up with a sleep() call.

Comment: Well, I'm not too worried about the actual mechanism used, but I would like to do it in a clean way. I'm more worried about sprinkling my code with stop signs...

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question. I won't accept it yet because this is only in concept stage.

I think I'll create a common stack for all calls to services belonging to my provider. Every time a call is made, I'll set up a 'cool down' period using some form of thread or timer (I'm tempted to use this as an excuse to include [gabr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4997/gabr)'s [OmniThread](http://otl.17slon.com/) library in my application.) So if two or more requests are submitted during the cool down period, I can chain them and show some fancy (*) user interface to the user to avoid event breakage.

If somebody has a better alternative, I'm all ears.

*(*): A dialog box with a progress bar, of course.*